# This my button and function for it. My question is, after click that button.. how to make it disable for 30 mins?

Tags: javascript

Down there is my button n function for that button in php, how to add disable button for 30 mins after clicking on it? I need help for it because im still newbie on php coding..

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 200px; outline: none;" id="testar" onclick="enviar()">START</button>
```

This my function:

```
      <script title="ajax do checker">
        function enviar() {
            var linha = $("#lista").val();
            var linhaenviar = linha.split("\n");
            var total = linhaenviar.length;
            var ap = 0;
            var ed = 0;
            var rp = 0;
            linhaenviar.forEach(function(value, index) {
                setTimeout(
                      function() {
                                var sec = $("#sec").val();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'g3api.php?lista=' + value,
                            type: 'GET',
                            async: true,
                            success: function(resultado) {
                                if (resultado.match("Approved")) {
                                    removelinha();
                                    ap++;
                                    aprovadas(resultado + "");
                                }else if(resultado.match("CCN")) {
                                    removelinha();
                                    ed++;
                                    edrovadas(resultado + "");
                                }else {
                                    removelinha();
                                    rp++;
                                    reprovadas(resultado + "");
                                }
                                $('#carregadas').html(total);
                                var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(ed) + parseInt(rp);
                                $('#cLive').html(ap);
                                $('#cWarn').html(ed);
                                $('#cDie').html(rp);
                                $('#total').html(fila);
                                $('#cLive2').html(ap);
                                $('#cWarn2').html(ed);
                                $('#cDie2').html(rp);
                            }
                        });
                    }, 5000 * index);
            });
        }
        function aprovadas(str) {
            $(".aprovadas").append(str + "<br>");
        }
        function reprovadas(str) {
            $(".reprovadas").append(str + "<br>");
        }
        function edrovadas(str) {
            $(".edrovadas").append(str + "<br>");
        }
        function removelinha() {
            var lines = $("#lista").val().split('\n');
            lines.splice(0, 1);
            $("#lista").val(lines.join("\n"));
        }
    
        function iloveyou(){
        alert('PEKPEK')}
    </script>
```

My question is: How to make the button disabled for 30 minutes after it's clicked?

Comment: You just have to store the information that it was clicked somewhere - browser session storage, cookie, server session, file, database... depends really on how strict you want this limitation to be.

Comment: How I able to do that?

Comment: By researching those options. Your question is too broad to be answered here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('clicked') === 'true') return;
    localStorage.setItem('clicked', 'true');
    button.disabled = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
        localStorage.removeItem('clicked');
        button.disabled = false;
    }, 60000 * 10);
});
```

Comment: Just add it below my function script?

Comment: Make sure that button refers to the button you're using.

Comment: So just need to paste it where? Sorry im still new

Comment: This will keep resetting the timer if the page is refreshed. The button won't be disabled anymore if the page is refreshed, which will in turn allow the other click event to still run.

Comment: You have any idea where should i put that script? and what should i edit by refer my script up there?